# openxml can't open docx file throught sharepoint rest

Tags: sharepoint, openxml

I'm using the sharepoint rest api to get the contents of a docx file like so

```
_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('openxmlJsPoc')/files('TemplateDocument.docx')/$value
```

I get the contents of the file, But I'm having trouble reading it with the openxml javascript api.

this is a sample the return data that I get:

```
PK     ! î¦o´•  )   Í[Content_Types].xml ¢É(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ¼•MKÃ@†ï‚ÿ!ìUš­
```

"ÒÔƒG¬àuÝLÚÅýbgÚÚï$Ú(Z[iª—@²;ïûì»3dpþâl6ƒ„&øBæ}‘×¡4~\ˆ‡ÑuïTdHÊ—Ê…X ŠóáþÞ`´ˆ€W{,Ä„(žI‰zNa"x^©BrŠø5eTúYAõû'ROà©Gµ†.¡RSKÙÕ~#I`Qdok¯B¨­ÑŠ˜TÎ|ùÅ¥÷îse³'&âc¹Ò¡^ùÙà½î–£I¦„ìN%ºQŽ1ä<¤R–AOŸ!_/³‚3T•ÑÐÖ×j1
ˆœ¹³y»â”ñKþ9ˆÙ<;³42-ˆ;Û};úRy#BÅ}1ROvÏÐJo„˜ÃÓýŸEñI|7Ë]
%Gç, ¿Ê÷c„DÚùYÕ­·i‹‹XÎk]ýKÇfòþ¢ùÝuaë)RpÎJCàšÜ:‡ÞŠÖz›Co·0tŸûVtk†ãÿÎá£ùšKÙ‘ýŠ>”Ínø
  ÿÿ PK     ! ™U~  á   ó_rels/.rels ¢ï(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ¬’ÏJÃ@Æï‚ï°Ì½™´Šˆ4éE„ÞDâ»Ó$˜ýÃîTÛ·w-ˆjÒƒÇùæ›ß|ìzs°ƒzç˜zï*X%(vÚ›Þµ¼6O‹{PIÈ¼ã
Žœ`S__­_x ÉC©ëCRÙÅ¥
:‘ð€˜tÇ–Rá»ÜÙùhIò3¶H¿QË¸*Ë;Œ¿= yª­© nÍ
¨æòæyo¿Ûõš½Þ[vrfòAØ6‹3[”>_£Š-KÆëç\NH!ð<Ñêr¢¿¯EËB†„PûÈÓ<_Š) åå@ó?é|øh0GtÊvŠæö?iô>‰·3ñœ4ßH8ú˜õ'   ÿÿ PK     ! v¥S¬"  Û   Ú word/_rels/document.xml.rels ¢Ö (                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ¬”ËjÃ0E÷…þƒÑ¾–í´i)‘³)…l[ºUäñƒêa¤I[ÿ}E ±Cƒ’…6‚¡{W#­Ö¿J&ß`]o4#yš‘´0u¯[F>ª×

which I'm positive its correct because when i save this as a docx file it opens correctly.

tried using

```
    openXml.OpenXmlPackage(result);  
    // and
    doc = new openXml.OpenXmlPackage(); 
    doc.openFromArrayBuffer
```

but I keep getting errors

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the JZIP.js that comes packaged with the sdk.

A better approac is to save the template as a Word xml file and then download it through ajax and open it.

worked for me